# Topologically, what is a 'string' from string theory?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, knot-theory, string-theory

To begin: I am not a crank. I am not sure how well-founded my titular question is, but it was interesting enough that I decided to bring it to MSE.

For context: I am an undergraduate mathematics student. I am taking a course in algebraic topology, and during class it was asked how algebraic topology applies to string theory. Our professor explained that he was not sure, but he knew there was some connection between knot theory and string theory. He said it may interesting to understand the topological role of a 'string,' and I assume this is contingent on the connection between knot theory and string theory being strong enough that such an analogy can be realized.

**So I am here to ask:**

1. Is the connection between string theory and (algebraic) topology strong enough that it makes sense to ask how a 'string' can be viewed topologically?
2. If so, what is a string from this topological point-of-view?

Comment: Please state your question clearly in the body of your post, not just in the title. It us very unhelpful to require us to jump around from the title to the body to understand your question.

Comment: @RobArthan 'Please state your question clearly in the body of your post'; I am unsure what you mean, I have a separated sentence beginning with 'So I am here to ask...' Do you mean you think it would be a good idea I move this bit to the very top of my post?

Comment: The question in your title doesn't really map directly to anything in the body of your question.

Comment: @RobArthan I have revised my questions somewhat.

Comment: Strings in the string theory sense are actually not knotted because the ambient dimension is too high.

Comment: Anyway, topologically a string is a 1 dimensional manifold: it can have constrained ends that need to lie on certain subspaces, or it can be a closed loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings in string theory are just one-dimensional manifolds embedded in a (usually) 10-dimensional space. The strings represent particles; the basic idea is to replace the pointlike concept of a particle in classical and (though it is more complicated here) quantum mechanics with a particle that is stringlike. This gives particles much more interesting behavior, such as the ability to have discrete vibrational modes. As for the strings themselves, there isn’t really a deeper connection to topology that I am aware of.

However, there are important connections between string theory and algebraic topology. This comes up in several places. I am not a string theorist, so I cannot enumerate all of these, but the main one has to do with the fact that string theories live in more than three spatial dimensions (most commonly ten). Since we only observe three dimensions, you have to explain why we don’t see the others. The oldest mechanism for this is Kaluza-Klein compactification, where the extra dimensions are like a compact manifold that is very small in size.  The manifold has to be a Calabi-Yau manifold, and topology is highly relevant to this part of the theory.

Comment: Normally I would accept this answer. But as I have no knowledge of string theory, I will wait a while before accepting, in case those who are more knowledgeable have something to add, or something like that.

Comment: Why has to be a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse I totally understand and am fine with you not accepting the answer for now.  I suspect if you asked this question on physics.SE you would get a lot more responses, though.

Comment: @DanielD I haven't studied string theory formally (though I have studied quantum field theory in depth).  I think that it's best for me to redirect you to other sources here.  [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253767/138837) is one example on physics.SE.  I doubt that this will make much sense without a particle physics background, rather like explaining a Calabi-Yau manifold to someone without a math major.  ...

Comment: ... But the basic idea is that physical quantities in any QFT are predicted by series that, in general, do not converge. Sometimes a symmetry in the theory can be used to show that the terms in the series will cancel and converge, but there are ["anomalies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_(physics)) where even this fails, often because the symmetry is violated by "quantizing" the theory. In special cases, you can show that the cancellation is valid even for an anomaly. In string theory, the [Green-Schwarz mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green-Schwarz_mechanism) is one such case.

Comment: I had read both Wikipedia articles before by curiosity but couldn't understand much and less that this was related to the need of Calabi-Yau manifolds (which I don't understand much either) but at least I think these ideas have a better order on my mind now, thank you very much

Comment: @DanielD I had thought that the Calabi-Yau manifolds were related to anomalies and the Green-Schwarz mechanism. I was reading about this today and realized that this isn't the direct reason, though it is related. The real reason that you need a Calabi-Yau manifold is because otherwise the extra dimensions would completely break supersymmetry, which is required for the cancellation I discussed earlier. I only have a vague notion of why this is, based on QFT, so hopefully we will get a real string theorist here at some point. ...

Comment: ... This will be unsatisfactory, but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking) is a page on the general topic in the context of QFT.

Comment: thanks for your clarification I was indeed confusing things but I still have a doubt, so Calabi-Yau comes from imposing supersymmetry on the extra dimension but then you said that supersymmetry is required for the cancellation and that last bit confused me because I thought it was added  as a condition after cancellation and not that was a needed condition from the start.

Comment: Supersymmetry is needed for multiple reasons to make the theory well-defined. One of the reasons is to cancel otherwise-divergent series coming from the anomaly. Any form for the extra dimensions other than a Calabi-Yau manifold would break the supersymmetry, but I don’t know enough string theory to fill in the actual details.